# CMD command execution

Tags: script, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am trying to execute a specific command in a bat script after finding the path to the folder.  Here is what I have so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
cmd /k "cd C:\"Program Files (x86)\"Microsoft Office\Office15\" 
cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus
pause
```

The issue I am having is executing the *cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus*

Comment: What error are you getting when you execute the cscript command?

Answer (score 4):

if this script is being saved as a .bat file, is there a reason you are telling the batch file to open another instance of command line?

For this simple script you shouldn't need to do that. Also, your path for cd should surround the entire line in double quotes. The following changes will work for your needs.

```
@ECHO OFF
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\"
cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus
pause
```

Comment: Unbelievable, Thank you so much Jessie.  I knew it was something little I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons why your script is failing:-

1. `cmd /k ...` creates a new instance of `cmd`, runs the specified command, then prompts from this instance and does not continue with the original `cmd` until you type `exit`.
2. Even if you had used `cmd /c ...` to execute a command string and exit immediately, the `cd` executing in the subshell would not affect the current directory in the original `cmd`.

To retain the current directory after the script has run, you can either use:

```
cmd /c "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\ & cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus"
```

or more simply don't use a subshell, but use `pushd` instead of `cd` and run `popd` after `cscript` returns:-

```
@ECHO OFF
pushd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\"
cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus
popd
pause
```